# Op-Amp output if supply voltage is zero

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I have a current source connected to the inverting terminal of the op-amp, with the non-inverting terminal grounded. There is a feedback resistor connecting the inverting terminal to the output of the op-amp. If I connect a ground connection to both the supply voltage points of the op-amp, what would my output be?
I do not know the specifics of some components. I am using a CD pickup unit (KSS-213C) which houses a photodiode IC (CXA2586M), of which, all photodiodes have this circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM8CtPm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: LM317 is a voltage regulator, not an op-amp.

Comment: I don't think you can assume a general answer to this question for all op amps.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question and greatly improve it by adding a schematic. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: 1. Depends on the opamp.  2. Depends on the opamp part number.  3. Depends on the opamp's exact part number.  4. GOTO #1.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, yes I got a bit confused there, it has now been corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @TonyM thank you for your advice. I am new to this platform and I am learning. I have updated things as per our guidance. Hope it is better!

Answer (score 1):

Basically all opamps I know ( mostly precision parts with GBW product smaller than 100 MHz) have overvoltage clamping diodes at the inputs. (I am not sure but maybe these are inevitable parasitic diodes.) When you push/pull current through an input of an unpowered opamp, these diodes will conduct the charge to the positive supply or from the negative supply.

Usually these diodes arent rated for a lot of current though (mAs). If the supplies are shorted both to GND, then you will just dump this charge into GND.

If you have actual supplies connected (though unpowered) and if you push enough current into the supplies, the opamp will eventually turn on and run off this current. However, to maintain this situation and keep the opamp powered, the input has to stick beyond the rail. Therefore, a likely output is positive/negative limit at the instantaneous supply voltage of the opamp.

If you push more current than the opamp needs to run and maintain its output, the supply voltage will rise until something gives way and blows up.

Comment: You never really answered the question. What is the output voltage under the described  conditions? 0.0 V? 0.7 V? Something else?

Comment: Depends on the specific opamp and whether current is into or out of the input.. But what I wrote are the things that I believe to be universal.

Comment: @tobalt, yes I am getting outputs similar to your predictions I think. I am getting an oscillating output (sinusoidal-like) when I am supposed to get a uniform one. Is it because the opamp cannot keep up?
Also, could you look into https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/563040/226798?

Answer (score 0):

Opamps have a high input impedance and they have a differential input. Therefore at the input there is usually a differential pair. In some cases there is a common drain amp before that, but both of these show a gate or base to the input, and therefore the input impedance of the opamp is very high even in such a deactivated case. Therefore the current from the photodiode will flow entirely through the resistor.

For sure there is an ESD protection at the inputs.  There is some chance that one of these diodes will conduct some current **if** the voltage at the input deviates from the ground. Photodiodes operate in reverse bias, so the ESD diode towards the positive supply could conduct a bit, though the order of magnitude of the current forced by the ESD diodes is hard to predict. Maybe its an issue, maybe its not.

**Note:** the ESD diodes can be "deactivated" if the supply connections is broken --- for example with a switch --- instead of shorting to ground.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one doubt though. If my opamp supply voltage is floated (or grounded) and my non-inverting input is also floated (or grounded), would my output essentially be the current from the photodiode and the resistor wire?

Comment: @Danush What do you call your "output"? If the opamp show a very high impedance between any two terminals, than no current will flow there, if there is any other path with a lower impedance.

Comment: By output, I mean the voltage output that comes from the opamp.

Comment: @Danush If you short the supplies to ground, nothing will come out of the opamp's output terminal.

Comment: But I AM getting an output! If I ground the supply voltage point and also attach a ground to the non-inverting terminal, I am getting some voltage when there is no light. And when there is light shown to the photodiode, the voltage drops.

Comment: If I also float the supply voltage points and the non-inverting terminal, I am also getting an output, where 
 reaction of the photodiode towards light is seen. Which is why I though maybe that the opamp is getting shorted and the output is from the wire from the diode -> feedback resistor -> output. Can that be true?

Answer (score -4):

Opamps are made of BJT transistor which are current driven devices , they require current not voltage to work as a control signal unlike FETs.Your photodiode acts like a current source so they take that current, convert it to voltage and produce a voltage output . I don't really understand where is the problem here.

Comment: I don't think you understand how BJT amplifiers, much less op-amps, work. There are several stages of amplification in an op amp and they require supply voltages to produce an output. Furthermore, it is not true that all op amps are constructed from BJTs.

Comment: A BJT doesnt require voltage as input to produce voltage in the output...Maybe you should refresh your knowledge...Also most of the OpAmps I know use BJT to amplify the signal...

Comment: So if I have **no voltage** between the base and emitter I can get a voltage on the collector? Or suppose I somehow inject current into the base, will a voltage appear on the collector **without anything connected to it**? Also, you should watch your sentence structure: "Opamps **are made** of BJT" is much, much different than "**most** of the OpAmps **I know** use BJT".

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes if you have a current source connected to the base of a BJT current will flow through the circuit and you will get voltage at the collector and the emitter.BJT's are current driven devices not voltage driven.

Comment: I wonder why Elliot didn't reply to that. So are you saying that there is 0V or no voltage across Input/Base and Emitter/Ground when you connected a current source to BJT's base? @MissMulan