# Photodiode IC giving non-intuitive outputs

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, photodiode

I am using a Photodiode IC ([CXA2586M](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/sony/a6802588.pdf%27)). This PDIC has multiple photodiodes but all of them have the same circuit. I have supplied voltages as per the datasheet (i.e Vcc = 5V, Vc = 1.5V) (See default circuit) . I am measuring voltages through an Arduino MEGA, so the reference voltage to the Arduino is Vc, just like how the datasheet says. When I operate the IC in these default settings, I get no output. But then I floated Vc (connection 8) and Vcc (connection 9) connections (and connect the Arduino GND to a power supply ground). When I shine some IR light on the PD, I get a voltage that is lesser than the voltage produced when there is no light. I first thought it must be because the output of the opamp is inverted and then added to Vc (=0?). If I connect Vc (connection 8) and Vcc (connection 9) to a common ground (with Arduino ground = common ground) I am getting the same results. Can someone explain why these three things are happening?

Default circuit:
[image: Default circuit]

EDIT 1:
The output of all 6 photodiodes (Ao, Bo, Co, Do, Eo and Fo) were taken after connecting arduino ground to common ground, just like @Circuitfantasist suggested, and is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a schematic showing how all of these devices are connected together. We also need you to add links to the manufacturer's datasheets for the photodiode IC and any other specific integrated circuits that are involved.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, the question has been edited. The schematics are in the datasheets. Thanks!

Comment: @Danush:  The datasheet schematic is one thing.  The way you have really connected the parts is another thing.  Draw schematic of the setup as you have built it.  Sometimes, the very act of drawing the schematic from the circuit helps you find the error yourself.  If not, then maybe it will help us to help you.

Comment: You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @JRE and Transistor. I completely take responsibility for not including any schematic. In fact, after reading ElliotAlderson's comment, I included the links to the datasheet. I have 0 experience in electronic circuits so I did not want to include circuits of my own creation. I hope the block diagram of the IC I copied from the datasheet helps you guys analyse the problem fastteer. Thanks and sorry!

Comment: Just draw your circuit.  Without that it is very difficult to answer your question.

Comment: @Danush If you want to ask about the circuit you're using, draw the circuit you're using.

Comment: Guys, is it better now? Where can I do better?

Comment: You have the Arduino ground hooked up to +1.5v? How are you powering the Arduino? The output signal will be referenced to Vc and negative (so 1.5v out when no signal and decreasing towards zero) since this is an inverting amplifier, and I don't think your Arduino can handle negative voltages, so this isn't going to work.

Comment: @user1850479 the Arduino is powered through the USB connector. But your second point is a bit off. Yes, it is an inverting terminal, but pay attention to the diode connection. The current that the photodiode will produce is towards the diode. So in the end, the output of the opamp = Vc + i*R, where i is the current produced by the diode and R is the feedback resistance.

Answer (score 0):

I will outline some general considerations that would help clarify the problem.

What I see inside the circuit are six transimpedance amplifiers with photodiodes connected to the op-amp inverting inputs. The current generated by the photodiode during illumination should enter its cathode so the output voltage of the op-amp should change in a positive direction.

The voltage Vc = 1.5 V applied to the non-inverting inputs "shifts up" the op-amp output zero level; so the output voltage will vary from 1.5 V to 5 V.

The reference voltage of the Arduino ADC should be 5 V and the Arduino ground should be connected to common ground.

Comment: I completely agree with your statement in your first three paragraphs @Circuitfantasist. I'd be grateful if you could clarify two doubts:

1) Now since the reference voltage of the photodiode output is Vc, shouldn't arduino ground be set to Vc?

2) If suppose what you say is true, I would like to know how does one set reference voltage of Arduino ADC to 5V if arduino ground is connected to common ground?

Comment: @Danush, The output voltage of the transimpedance amplifier ("photodiode output") is referenced to ground. So, the input voltage of the ADC Arduino is also referenced to ground... and the Arduino ground should be connected to the common ground (i.e., there is only one ground). To set the ADC reference voltage to 5 V just connect VREF pin to +5 V. See this [circuit diagram](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/admux-register-in-arduino-mega/602095).

Comment: Ok @Circuitfantasist, thanks a lot for guidance wrt Arduinos. 
Coming to the second and more fundamental question. How is voltage reducing in magnitude if light is being shown to the photodiode? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Only to ask, "Is this a voltage measured by a voltmeter connected between the op-amp output and the common ground? Or this is a voltage measured by the ADC and the software?" Measure it by a voltmeter to be sure what happens.

Comment: Let's check it again... The photodiode is reverse-biased because of the positive bias voltage Vc applied to the non-inverting input. So, "if light is being shown to the photodiode", it produces a current flowing internally from the cathode to the anode. It creates a voltage drop across the feedback resistor with "-" to the inverting input. So, the op-amp begins raising its (positive) output voltage until restores the equality getween its input voltages -  V(-) = V(+). Simply speaking, the photodiode acts as a negative input source that makes the op-amp increase its positive output voltage...

Comment: I have taken some readings today. I have edited my question and it now includes the output. @Circuitfantasist, there are still two questions that need addressing. 1) Why is the output sinusoidal-like? 2) We see the output voltage decreases as light is being shown. Now is that because Voutput = Vc - (Voltage from photodiode)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123740/discussion-between-circuit-fantasist-and-danush).